# Can I login using SOAP in a scratch org's primary domain?

Tags: soap-api, soap, login

I have used test.salesforce.com to perform SOAP API logins before. However, due to a security issue we cannot do that right now. Is there a way to login to:

```
`https://[base-url]/services/Soap/u/58.0`
```

instead of:

```
https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/58.0
```

as a SOAP API login? If so, what is the syntax for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SOAP exists in Scratch Orgs, so you can login and access all the APIs. Note that you should prefer to use the scratch org's domain instead of test.salesforce.com anyways.

Comment: how is the endpoint address constructed? the way I have it above isn't working. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: @seekingPeace See [login()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm). They specify you should use `mydomain.my.salesforce.com` as the login endpoint.